# Crashing on setValue:forKey:

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

Crashlytics reported a crash in my app, and I have no idea of what is happening.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x30080e83 __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a3dd6c7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreData                       0x2fdcf941 -[NSSQLiteStatement cachedSQLiteStatement]
3  CoreData                       0x2fdcf18d -[NSSQLiteConnection prepareSQLStatement:] + 52
4  CoreData                       0x2fde8edf -[NSSQLChannel selectRowsWithCachedStatement:] + 58
5  CoreData                       0x2fea8e1f newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 910
6  CoreData                       0x2fde8949 -[NSSQLCore fetchRowForObjectID:] + 1180
7  CoreData                       0x2fde8311 -[NSSQLCore newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 256
8  CoreData                       0x2fde762b _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 398
9  CoreData                       0x2fde7193 _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 218
10 CoreData                       0x2fdf6449 _PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex + 68
11 CoreData                       0x2fdf636b _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 110
12 CoreData                       0x2fe1995d _PF_Handler_Public_SetProperty + 92
13 CoreData                       0x2fe1e2a9 -[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:] + 124
14 Application                    0x0004dc45 -[DateFormatter storeValue:error:] (DateFormatter.m:65)
15 Application                    0x0004ee17 -[Formatter storeValue:inObject:] (Formatter.m:176)
16 Application                    0x0002b5c5 -[NSManagedObject(App) setValuesForKeysWithReceivedDictionary:] (NSManagedObject+App.m:320)
17 Application                    0x0002b8f3 -[NSManagedObject(App) setValuesForKeysWithReceivedDictionary:] (NSManagedObject+App.m:377)
18 Application                    0x0006352d -[ODataGetOperation processResult:] (ODataGetOperation.m:220)
19 Application                    0x0004420b -[ODataOperation connectionDidFinishLoading:] (ODataOperation.m:741)
20 Foundation                     0x309bb47f __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 54
21 Foundation                     0x309bb3c1 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 204
22 Foundation                     0x309bb2dd -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 60
23 CFNetwork                      0x2fceaf8f ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 74
24 CFNetwork                      0x2fce9b8f ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 54
25 CFNetwork                      0x2fd1b337 ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 18
26 CoreFoundation                 0x2ffb3ea1 CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
27 CFNetwork                      0x2fc81e05 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 164
28 CFNetwork                      0x2fc81cd5 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 220
29 CFNetwork                      0x2fc81b65 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 48
30 CoreFoundation                 0x3004bf1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
31 CoreFoundation                 0x3004b3e7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
32 CoreFoundation                 0x30049bd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 630
33 CoreFoundation                 0x2ffb4471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
34 CoreFoundation                 0x2ffb4253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
35 Foundation                     0x309a2697 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 254
36 Application                    0x00043b4b -[ODataOperation send] (ODataOperation.m:548)
37 Application                    0x0004277f -[ODataOperation operationWillStartPreparingData] (ODataOperation.m:131)
38 Foundation                     0x30a5396d __NSOQSchedule_f + 60
39 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a8c64b7 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 110
40 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a8c77d9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 224
41 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a8c79c5 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
42 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a9f1dff _pthread_wqthread + 298
43 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a9f1cc4 start_wqthread + 8
```

And there is the last method that calls setValue:forKey: in an NSManagedObject subclass

```
- (BOOL)storeValue:(void *)theValue error:(NSError **)theError
{
    NSString * value = (__bridge NSString *)theValue;
    NSString * errorMessage = nil;
        if (![value length] && !isOptional)
        errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"Value cannot be nil or empty (Date) for field %@", @""), varName];
        else
        {
        NSDate * date = nil;
        if ([value length])
        {
            date = [NSDate dateWithISO8601: value];
            if (!date)
                errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"Invalid date %@ for field %@", @""), theValue, varName];
        }
        if (IvarAddress)
            *((__strong NSDate **) IvarAddress) = date;
        else
            [currentObject setValue: date forKey: varName];
        }

    if (errorMessage)
    {
        if (theError)
            *theError = [NSError errorWithDomain: AppDomain code: NSFormattingError userInfo: @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: errorMessage }];
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Formatter error: %@", errorMessage);
#endif
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I am completely open to any suggestion :)

Update : The key exists, and the value being set is an NSDate so it's an attribute of the NSManagedObject, not a relationship.

Update 2 :

I also have another crash with that method (stack trace is not exactly the same) :

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x30080e83 __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a3dd6c7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreData                       0x2fddfacb -[NSSQLCore _obtainOpenChannel] + 234
3  CoreData                       0x2fea8ded newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 860
4  CoreData                       0x2fde8949 -[NSSQLCore fetchRowForObjectID:] + 1180
5  CoreData                       0x2fde8311 -[NSSQLCore newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 256
6  CoreData                       0x2fde762b _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 398
7  CoreData                       0x2fde7193 _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 218
8  CoreData                       0x2fdf6449 _PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex + 68
9  CoreData                       0x2fdf636b _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 110
10 CoreData                       0x2fe1995d _PF_Handler_Public_SetProperty + 92
11 CoreData                       0x2fe1e2a9 -[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:] + 124
12  Application               0x000fcc45 -[DateFormatter storeValue:error:] (DateFormatter.m:65)
13  Application               0x000fde17 -[Formatter storeValue:inObject:] (Formatter.m:176)
14  Application               0x000da5c5 -[NSManagedObject(App) setValuesForKeysWithReceivedDictionary:] (NSManagedObject+.m:320)
15  Application               0x000da8f3 -[NSManagedObject(App) setValuesForKeysWithReceivedDictionary:] (NSManagedObject+.m:377)
16  Application               0x0011252d -[ODataGetOperation processResult:] (ODataGetOperation.m:220)
17  Application               0x000f320b -[ODataOperation connectionDidFinishLoading:] (ODataOperation.m:741)
18 Foundation                     0x309bb47f __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 54
19 Foundation                     0x309bb3c1 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 204
20 Foundation                     0x309bb2dd -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 60
```

The exception message also is different :

_obtainOpenChannel -- NSSQLCore 0x15ef3780: no database channel is available

But I think they are two related issues.

Comment: It seems something wrong with the key according to the official comment: **If key is not a property defined by the model, the method raises an exception. If key identifies a to-one relationship, relates the object specified by value to the receiver, unrelating the previously related object if there was one. Given a collection object and a key that identifies a to-many relationship, relates the objects contained in the collection to the receiver, unrelating previously related objects if there were any.**

Comment: The key exists, it corresponds to an NSDate attribute, not a relationship.

Comment: what key are you using - and whats the message of the exception

Comment: is the property transient or stored

Comment: I don't know what key was used, but I have a lot of transient in the model, so if you think it is related...

Comment: The exception message is : statement is still active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally found the reasons which were all related to multithreading/concurrency issues. Basically updating the same objects on two threads at the same time..

The recently added core data debug flags (-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1) were used to figure out what was happening.